# Simple Explanation of Poodle Vulnerability?

Tags: security, ssl

Because of my work, I was aware of the POODLE vulnerability within minutes of it being announced. We of course disabled SSL 3.0 everywhere relevant. However, I still don't really understand how the vulnerability works.

I read the article published by the Google researchers here: https://www.openssl.org/~bodo/ssl-poodle.pdf, but don't really understand the "padding" spoken of. I believe there will be others with similar questions. Can someone provide a clear and simple explanation of how an attacker would exploit the POODLE vulnerability, and how encryption would be broken?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. http://security.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask.

Comment: Excuse my noob-ness, you are right. Is there a way to migrate this question there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. It would be on-topic on [security.se] and a broader question has been asked there: [SSL3 “POODLE” Vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70719/ssl3-poodle-vulnerability) (as well as [many other questions on POODLE](http://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Apoodle))

Comment: @Gilles, I'd be happy to just delete it, if that helps. I didn't initially do so because someone posted an answer. I'm content with whatever course of action improves SO the most. :)

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my english, please.
According to my understanding as follows:

Padding Oracle On Downgraded Legacy Encryption

Meaning - calculate HttpRequestHeaders of encrypted request. Of greatest interest are the secret cookie or basic-authentication.

Necessary - man-in-the-middle attack (opportunity to pretend to be the server for the client, and the client - for the server).

Vulnerable - super-secret sites that are trying to deal with mitm attacks by hiding authenticity and user preferences using https, but allowing to use SSLv3.0 in CBC mode.

mechanism -

1) An attacker injects in usual page Javascript that sends secret requests to the server (via the attacker) and gets commands through the responses.

2) At the first request attacker waits until browser downgrades to SSLv3.0 in CBC mode.

3) lengthen the path and body requests, an attacker tries to get header byte to attack was the last one of the block to encrypt, and the length of the request without padding was divided by the length of the encryption block (L) evenly. (in this case, the last block of text to encrypt will contain the debris and the last byte of the length of this collection, that is, L-1)

4) replaces the last block of the encrypted contents to the encrypted request block, which has byte to attack, and sends request to the server.

5) If the request to the server accepted, the attacker can calculate the value of the attacked byte, otherwise he has to try again, starting with a request from the client (to get temporary encryption key is changed and re-encryption proceed.)

Mathematics -

P and C - plain and cipher text, respectively, as arrays of blocks, each of which is an array of bytes, Dk - decryption function. i - number of the block containing attacked byte, n - number of the last block.

P [i] [L-1] === Dk (C [i]) [L-1] ^ C [i-1] [L-1]

L-1 === P [n] [L-1] === Dk (C [n] === C [i]) [L-1] ^ C [n-1] [L-1]

Combining, we obtain

P [i] [L-1] = C [i-1] [L-1] ^ C [n-1] [L-1] ^ L-1